# Custom Security Sample for SSRS 2019

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

.I am implement base on Instructions in readme in this [github.com](https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample)
and create usename and password and salt in database UserAccounts.
When I log in to the browser, it asks me again for my username and password, and when I give it the username and password that is stored in the DataBase, it shows an error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the result.
I handed over all the steps to the script powershell .
in address `Reporting-Services/CustomSecuritySample/Configure.ps1`
But before that, I stopped the Report service and after running it again, I started the service .